# REACT : hide parent component when child component has an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have components like this

- < Parent container>

  - < image description>
  - < image container>

    - < image tag>
    - < image caption text>

how this works is parent container has a name of a city which it passes down to image container

which makes a search query with that city to make some image URL

now that image url is passed to  image tag

now when that image url is failing to fetch source, image is coming as blank, but other things like image description which are higher up in heirarchy are still showing up..

I can handle image load failure at image container level maybe, but how to percolate this to parent container so that parent container itself hides when image load fails

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend giving this a read around [Lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.)

It sounds to me like you're making an API call to get an image, which may not always exist, and then to render other components based on this. The API call could be lifted to the top parent container, and render the child components based on the result of this call.

The `parent` makes the call to get the image, and then there you can decide what you want to render based on success or failure.

Comment: Thanks.. Thinking in same direction.. But this way I might to have change many things as I have only given simpler parts of the hierarchy.. I posted this question to see if I can find any alternative.. Thanks for ur input anyways

Comment: This is just "reacts way" of doing things - it has uni directional binding, where data is only passed one way. A child component telling a parent component not to render it for a given reason, that whole logic should be the parent deciding whether the child should render. Flip the idea of it in your head, might make it easier to approach. Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass in a callback prop for this type of event:

```
function ImageComponent({ imageSrc, onImageLoadError }) {
  return (
    <img onError={onImageLoadError} src={imageSrc} />
  );
}
```

and then in you ParentComponent:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = React.useState("some_image_url");
  const handleImageLoadError = () => {
    // do something in case of error (show a default image etc)
    setImgSrc('default_image_which_loads');
  };

  return (
    <ImageComponent imageSrc={imgSrc} onImageLoadError={handleImageLoadError} />
  )
}
```

or if you want to hide the image component you can do that as well:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [imgHasError, setImgHasError] = React.useState(false);
  const handleImageLoadError = () => {
    // hide image in case of error
    setImgHasError(true);
  };

  return (
    {imgHasError ? null : (<ImageComponent imageSrc={imgSrc} onImageLoadError={handleImageLoadError} />)}
  )
}
```

Comment: Will this not create infinite loop like.. Child ask parent to render.. Which will render child again?

Comment: when an error happens you replace the image with a default image which will load. Why do you think this will create an infinite loop? Edited the answer to show what I mean

Comment: Infinite loop.. Bcoz.. Child update parent which which updates parent which will re render child and so on

Comment: Why will the child update the parent which will update the child again? when you receive an error for the current URL you replace the image with a default one, or you hide it completely (added another example for you)

Comment: OK.. Will try to implement it first.. Appreciate ur input on this